# Async Task Best Practice

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In regards to Async Task in android it is best practice to include them as a Inner Class of the Activity you are working in or is it better to have the as their own stand alone class? for example

```
public MyClass extents Activity
{
       public void onCreate(){
       }

       public class MyAsyncTask extents AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
       {
               protected void doInBackground()
               {
                     //do stuff here....
               }
       }
       public void onResume(){
       }
}
```

or as an external class

```
public class MyAsyncTask extents AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
       protected void doInBackground()
       {
           //do stuff here....
       }
}


public MyClass extents Activity
{
       public void onCreate(){
       }
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you're doing - there really is no "best way". If it's large / long, I'd put it in it's own file, just like for any other class, so that your code is not messy. But it really doesn't matter otherwise. Also, worth noting that Stack Overflow is not really the right place for "opinion" questions - you may get a better answer elsewhere.

Comment: @JonasCz Well, it matters in fact... It would be no matter if inner class would be static. In other case it contains reference to outer class and it is wrong if it is an Activity as Asynctask may live longer.

Comment: @Selvin - That doesn't make it "wrong"...that just means you have to deal with those references and make sure it's all handled properly during lifecycle changes, which is all possible. And this is an issue that can come up even when the AsyncTask is in a separate class file as well.

Comment: You cannot get rid of references of outer class in inner non static class... So even if you make AsyncTask survive fx orientation change and you retain it in new Activity, it is wrong as old Activity should released but there in no way for doing this ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AsyncTask` has it's own lifecycle which doesn't depend on `Activity` lifecycle. You need to make sure that it doesn't have a reference to activity or views when activity is already destroyed.

Implementing `AsyncTask` as an inner class makes sense only if it's `static`. If it's not static then it will have an implicit reference to outer activity which will lead to memory leaks. If you need references to views from your static async task use `WeakReference`.

Implementing `AsyncTask` in a separate file is also a good idea, but same rules applied. Use weak references if needed.

The only difference between `static` inner async task and async task in a separate file is code readability. If there is a lot of logic inside async task, go ahead with a separate file.

Comment: I use inner AsyncTask because I need to update UI like show/hide loader and update ConversationAdapter list but I didn't mention as static because there is lot of fields like show/hide component to be static and ConversaationList also. So i need a confirmation does this lead memory leak or use more memory